# web.py is blocked when using multiprocess-lib

Tags: python, uwsgi, web.py, multiprocess

It seems to work different.  One is very slow and anthor is very fast.
Just because [import demo] ? why?

The slow one:

[demo_app.py]

```
import web
urls = ('/(.*)', 'demo.hello')
app = web.application(urls, globals())
application = app.wsgifunc()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

[demo.py]

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
tmp  = Manager()
class hello:
def GET(self,name):
    return 'Hello world'
```

[run with uwsgi]
    uwsgi  -d demo.log --http 127.0.0.1:8893 -w demo_app -p 1

[curl http://127.0.0.1: 8893/] is very slow

---

The OK(fast) one :

[demo_app.py]

```
import web
import demo
urls = ('/(.*)', 'demo.hello')
app = web.application(urls, globals())
application = app.wsgifunc()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

[demo.py]

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
tmp  = Manager()
class hello:
def GET(self,name):
    return 'Hello world'
```

[run with uwsgi]
    uwsgi  -d demo.log --http 127.0.0.1:8893 -w demo_app -p 1

[curl  is fast

—————————————————————

In the 'slow' one , I strace(linux)  the subprocess(uwsgi forked). After uwsgi writing the content, it will epoll_wait 60s. The parameters epoll_event in epoll_wait function is empty. look at the pic below:
[strace log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jucGp.png)

Comment: First request is very slow。 and The second time is ok .

Comment: There is anther question: if remove (tmp = Manager()) , the slower one is become fast. Thist code (tmp=Manager()) cost more than 30s, I dont think it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

With the fast one, you've imported demo on program start (i.e., during uwsgi startup). Therefore, no additional overhead during the HTTP request.

With the slow one, demo is imported on first HTTP request (i.e., during curl). Once it has been loaded times are the same.

Comment: Thank you Peter. But there is anther question:   if remove (tmp  = Manager())  , the slower one is become fast.  Thist code (tmp=Manager())   cost more than 30s, I dont think it make sense.

Comment: I see what you mean. In my case, "slow" is 1minute, which looks like a timeout failure rather the simply running slowly. Even providing `--enable-threads` with uwsgi doesn't help. I suspect thread deadlock & wonder if your fast / slow examples will even work for multiprocessing under web.py (Have you gotten that far?)

Comment: 1,Yes. it will cost 1minute.  I strace the subprocess, You can see the pic in the questions. 2,Yes. multiprocess will be work, I have done some experiments.  3. I suspect this is a bug in uwsgi, and I will check the source code...